# R Date conversion for multiple data types

Tags: r, excel, date, lubridate

It's easy enough to convert Excel dates to R dates with the `as.Date()` function:

```
as.Date(12345, origin = "1899-12-30")
#> [1] "1933-10-18"
```

How do I convert the following to R date class?

```
as.Date(c("-", "TBD", NA, 12345), origin = "1899-12-30")
#> Error in charToDate(x) : 
#>   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

The output would look like this. If it's not an Excel date just mark it `NA`.

```
#> [1] NA
#> [2] NA
#> [3] NA
#> [4] "1933-10-18"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up front:

```r
v <- c("-", "TBD", NA, 12345)
as.Date(as.integer(v), origin="1899-12-30")
# Warning in as.Date(as.integer(c("-", "TBD", NA, 12345)), origin = "1899-12-30") :
#   NAs introduced by coercion
# [1] NA           NA           NA           "1933-10-18"
```

As long as you have `c("-", ..., 12345)`, the `12345` will never match because it is coerced to a `character` within the vector. The only reason the above trick works is that it undoes that coercion.